# Typescript: Return array of mapped objects based on string[]

Tags: typescript, casting

I want to create a function that returns the mongo collections i need, based on a string array.

Here is where I am at right now.

```js
type CollectionNames = 'users' | 'orders';

type CollectionMap = {
  users: User;
  orders: Order;
};

type CollectionsArray<T extends CollectionNames[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: mongodb.Collection<CollectionMap[T[K]]>;
};

type CollectionAndConn<T extends CollectionNames[]> = {
  conn: mongodb.MongoClient;
  collections: CollectionsArray<T>; //mongodb.Collection<CollectionMap[T]>[];
};

export const mongo = async <T extends CollectionNames[]>(collectionNames: T): Promise<CollectionAndConn<T>> => {
  const conn = await MongoClient.connect(`${MONGO_URL}`, {});

  return {
    conn,
    collections: collectionNames.map((collectionName) => conn.db().collection(collectionName)) as CollectionsArray<T>,
  };
};
```

And here is how I want to call it:

```js
    const {
      conn,
      collections: [usersCollection, ordersCollection],
    } = await mongo(['users', 'orders']);
```

Right now my TS thinks that both userCollection and ordersCollection is a `mongodb.Collection<User | Order>` where I want it to know that userCollection should be `mongodb.Collection<User>` and ordersCollection should be `mongodb.Collection<Order>` based on the string[] I pass to the function.

/Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace `collectionNames: T` with `collectionNames: [...T]` in the definition of `mongo`, TypeScript will regard T as a tuple type and infer the correct return type:

```
const mongo = async <T extends CollectionNames[]>(
  collectionNames: [...T]
): Promise<CollectionAndConn<T>> => {
  ..
}
```

```
const {
  conn,
  collections: [usersCollection, ordersCollection],
  // (property) collections: [mongodb.Collection<User>, mongodb.Collection<Order>]
} = await mongo(['users', 'orders']);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCCA7A5hAJgIzgMyhEOAckVQ0yIChKYBPMAUzgFUBnBqOAXjgG8BXdlABccVjCjBUAXxr0mAeSjoO3PtBUixEqSllzGcAMIQANqYYBjGMGQA5AIYgGrNUUEdWROAB9iGzyIAbmo6QxNzKxtkAFkHMDVeSjg4DyhWUTYOEJSA9NElTRDpEIMmCItrWyRWAEEoKAdaAB4AFTgGAA8YBiR0Vwqo6sdnVgBtAF0APkTkuDGAaTgpOABrBloIHDhWidFSNCwAOkGq5GbT6KQ4sDHWxYnp4tKw8rNKq9q+kyQkNo7ur1+sZ3kN7E4XJMZjwkilLMgkPtkIdMEcYsiIEZTMBejAcnB4ZEzjVRJdqnUGk02lMgnAAPR0g7kE6g4kXVlXG53aaTZ7UeE1eBMtQOVi0JCWOD-Lo9PoDDnDCHjaYACkJH0Vo1EYyOut2AEpRAAFfAgYDsdlEz7fBHU6EzWEE5DiJ2-RLSOCiz1IWj0umegDuDmA8HRZCxOKQMCOAqQURVAAMACS8GIKOwAcQUAH1mAAlAAy0gTABo+NJ9aUUlAGDB+FAkHw5nCESXm06reTROqwUgRi4jiB4iq1Qrwc59dwZrGjlgVfqY2OkKPO+OGPrJ16yc76o0Wq0pm2UiVKCfKAKXY7Y0eOxrndq0qxt0gy3kn0uJjeGXAAHoAflPEUgxDBAMRVMZ3CELwyyIN8iAmStKCAA)

Comment: Wow. 3 dots did the trick. Didn't know that trick  Thank you